# Invoke Instagram share intents / iOS hooks from a web page (not app)

Tags: android, ios, android-intent, instagram

The Instagram app on iPhone and Android allow other apps to send it a photo for sharing via [intents](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/) / [hooks](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/).

Is it possible to invoke those those using JavaScript on a regular web page, if it happens to be accessed from an Android or iOS device? If so, how?